# Regx for extracting substring from in between data using java

Tags: java, html, regex

```
String line = "asdasdasdasd <meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress 3.5.2\" /> asdasdasdasdasd";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"WordPress\\s+([\\d.]+)\" />");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if(m.matches())
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
else
     System.out.println("not found");
```

The **regex** I have used does not give the desired result. I want the wordpress version from the supplied string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) matches at the beginning of the string. So, you would need to build regex for complete string.

Alternatively, you can use [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) with just the regex for relevant part of the string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("content=\"WordPress\\s+([\\d.]+)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if(m.find())
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
else
     System.out.println("not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the dot and accept more numbers just in case

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("WordPress\\s+([\\d+\\.]+)");
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` in a character class. And also `+` doesn't act as quantifier there. There is nothing wrong with the regex, just the way it is used.